# Xamarin.Forms Live Player - Unsupported Device due to API Version

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, xamarin-live-player

I'm trying to deploy an Android App using Xamarin.Forms Live Player. The issue I'm running into is that I get all of my devices are showing as unsupported, even though they are on very recent API versions

[image: Unsupported Device]

I set my minimum API version to 15 in the manifest file.

[image]

Some things that I tried:

1. Made sure all SDKs of the versions I am trying (8.1, 8.0, 4.0.3 are installed)
2. Cleared bin and obj directories
3. Restarted Visual studio

Are their other common issues that lead to "Unsupported Device" as a general error message?